# Some lightweight linux distros for AMD E-1800 APU laptop with 4GB RAM

Tags: linux, operating-system, cpu, hardware

I have a TurboX Laptop with AMD E-1800 APU with 4GB RAM, I use it for development purposes, but the CPU is not working well, i have installed ubuntu 16.04 amd64 on it. Whenever i load more than two tabs in chromium it gets more slower,even gets more worst while working in IDEs. Cant afford new one right now. Any suggestions about some lightweight linux distros to work on development and with easy package installation like lamp, Android Studio and NetBeans etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Good morning my friend,

I think that the major problem here is your hardware. 
In every distro it will be slow with so less RAM and an unpowerfull CPU like that.

Although, you can try Lubuntu or Puppy and see if your situation will get improved.

BR, 
Loukas